# Deriving the time zone from the city

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm working on an application that among other things gets a customer's city from that customer's data in a table via an AJAX call to an external web service that I can't modify. The city is usually formatted as "City, Country" (for example "Tampa, US"). Using this information in JavaScript and only this information is it possible to get the GMT Offset and Time Zone that the customer is in?

Comment: I'd say no, since time zones change depending on what day of the year it is.  Not to mention, *city, country* can be ambiguous.

Comment: No, using that information and only that information, it is not possible to get much of anything, as javascript has no notion of cities, and you'd need a lot more data, such as a map of all cities and their timezones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make another AJAX call to services like

- https://www.mashape.com/seikan/timezonedb-find-local-time-zone-by-coordinate-or-name
- http://www.worldweatheronline.com/time-zone-api.aspx
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/

Just of the top of my head, probably there're others out there, both commercial and free.